# Select an arrray from JSON data on PHP

Tags: php, json, api

everyone!

I'm working on a movie website(which obviously not completed). I want to know how to export data from an API and select an array from JSON data on PHP. In this case, I want to output the title of the movie but it seems to not working.

I get this error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object.
```

From the error, I know that I'm trying to output an object, not a string but I don't know how to resolve it.

Here's my index.php file:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/variables.php');
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <body>
    <?php
        echo $movieNameList->data->movies[1]->id;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

includes/variables.php file:

```
 <?php
 $getMovieList = file_get_contents('https://yts.to/api/v2/list_movies.json');
 $movieNameList = json_decode($getMovieList[0]);
 ?>
```

https://yts.to/api/v2/list_movies.json file if you're lazy:

```
{  
   "status":"ok",
   "status_message":"Query was successful",
   "data":{  
      "movie_count":4220,
      "limit":2,
      "page_number":1,
      "movies":[  
         {  
            "id":4247,
            "url":"https:\/\/yts.to\/movie\/rem-by-mtv-2014",
            "imdb_code":"tt4066748",
            "title":"R.E.M. by MTV",
            "title_long":"R.E.M. by MTV (2014)",
            "slug":"rem-by-mtv-2014",
            "year":2014,
            "rating":8,
            "runtime":107,
            "genres":[  
               "Documentary"
            ],
            "language":"English",
            "mpa_rating":"Unknown",
            "background_image":"https:\/\/s.ynet.io\/assets\/images\/movies\/rem_by_mtv_2014\/background.jpg",
            "small_cover_image":"https:\/\/s.ynet.io\/assets\/images\/movies\/rem_by_mtv_2014\/small-cover.jpg",
            "medium_cover_image":"https:\/\/s.ynet.io\/assets\/images\/movies\/rem_by_mtv_2014\/medium-cover.jpg",
            "state":"ok",
            "torrents":[  
               {  
                  "url":"https:\/\/yts.to\/torrent\/download\/1F28D13F40AE91AECC58D649F5F9D84D29321632.torrent",
                  "hash":"1F28D13F40AE91AECC58D649F5F9D84D29321632",
                  "quality":"720p",
                  "seeds":1063,
                  "peers":544,
                  "size":"812.23 MB",
                  "size_bytes":851680192,
                  "date_uploaded":"2015-06-28 08:49:09",
                  "date_uploaded_unix":1435438149
               },
               {  
                  "url":"https:\/\/yts.to\/torrent\/download\/DED26397FD36DFC932BB5EEEC82D25204699943C.torrent",
                  "hash":"DED26397FD36DFC932BB5EEEC82D25204699943C",
                  "quality":"1080p",
                  "seeds":247,
                  "peers":419,
                  "size":"1.65 GB",
                  "size_bytes":1766838835,
                  "date_uploaded":"2015-06-28 22:55:41",
                  "date_uploaded_unix":1435488941
               }
            ],
            "date_uploaded":"2015-06-28 08:49:06",
            "date_uploaded_unix":1435438146
         },
         {  
            "id":4245,
            "url":"https:\/\/yts.to\/movie\/bigfoot-county-2012",
            "imdb_code":"tt2108605",
            "title":"Bigfoot County",
            "title_long":"Bigfoot County (2012)",
            "slug":"bigfoot-county-2012",
            "year":2012,
            "rating":2.9,
            "runtime":82,
            "genres":[  
               "Horror",
               "Mystery"
            ],
            "language":"English",
            "mpa_rating":"R",
            "background_image":"https:\/\/s.ynet.io\/assets\/images\/movies\/bigfoot_county_2012\/background.jpg",
            "small_cover_image":"https:\/\/s.ynet.io\/assets\/images\/movies\/bigfoot_county_2012\/small-cover.jpg",
            "medium_cover_image":"https:\/\/s.ynet.io\/assets\/images\/movies\/bigfoot_county_2012\/medium-cover.jpg",
            "state":"ok",
            "torrents":[  
               {  
                  "url":"https:\/\/yts.to\/torrent\/download\/25E5FBDAD49BFD067EEB7778EF1CED753E0E608C.torrent",
                  "hash":"25E5FBDAD49BFD067EEB7778EF1CED753E0E608C",
                  "quality":"720p",
                  "seeds":324,
                  "peers":183,
                  "size":"693.01 MB",
                  "size_bytes":726671831,
                  "date_uploaded":"2015-06-27 14:02:07",
                  "date_uploaded_unix":1435370527
               }
            ],
            "date_uploaded":"2015-06-27 14:02:06",
            "date_uploaded_unix":1435370526
         }
      ]
   },
   "@meta":{  
      "server_time":1435498431,
      "server_timezone":"Pacific\/Auckland",
      "api_version":2,
      "execution_time":"12.3 ms"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your error

```
 <?php
 $getMovieList = file_get_contents('https://yts.to/api/v2/list_movies.json');
 $movieNameList = json_decode($getMovieList[0]);  // <-- Error line
 ?>
```

Should be

```
 <?php
 $getMovieList = file_get_contents('https://yts.to/api/v2/list_movies.json');
 $movieNameList = json_decode($getMovieList);
 ?>
```

The result of the file_get_content is a simple string and not an array

Comment: well, f*king thank god :D. I've forgotten about the file_get_contents function.

Comment: also, how to select, for instance, the second array? example, the Bigfoot Country movie. echo $movieNameList->data->movies[1]->title; where should I change?

Comment: You are selecting the second array occurance when using [1] remember arrays start at [0]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are typing the correct key names. This reference to the title is valid:

```
<?php
$movieNameList->data->movies[1]->title;
```

You could also either decode the json as arrays by setting the second argument to true:

```
json_decode($getMovieList, true);
```

or cast a property to a string:

```
echo (string) $object->property;
```

## Edit:

This line:

```
$movieNameList = json_decode($getMovieList[0]);
```

should be:

```
$movieNameList = json_decode($getMovieList);
```

Comment: nah still the same. the problem here is I want to know how to select an array. For example, I want to get the title of the first movie, which is R.E.M. by MTV.

Comment: Check new info in my answer

Comment: thank you all :D. also, how to select another array? example, how to select the bigfoot country movie?